# RLC - CLR - RCL Transfer function

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance, laplace-transform

I have problem because I don’t understand the difference between CLR RLC and LCR, they are the same no ? They have the same composant just placed in different ways, I did already found the Transfer function of RLC function but I just to know first in what there is a difference with these 3 circuit and if yes how should I will implement transfer function with Laplace of RCL and CLR circuit. Thanks for reading my post, sorry for my bad English and  have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They have the same composant just placed in different ways, I did
>   already found the Transfer function of RLC function

Whether the circuit is a series RLC, or a parallel RLC, the *order* of the three circuit elements is generally irrelevant.

What is important to understand is that are several transfer functions defined that depend on the choice of input and output variables.

For example, consider the *series* RLC driven by a sinusoidal voltage source of (angular) frequency $\omega$.

The input variable is, in this case, the voltage across the voltage source. The question is then: across which circuit element(s) is the output voltage taken?

If the output voltage is the voltage across the capacitor, then we have a 2nd order low-pass filter with transfer function:

$$\frac{V_C}{V_{in}}=\frac{1}{(1 - \omega^2LC)+j\omega RC}$$

If the output voltage is the voltage across the inductor, then we have a 2nd order high-pass filter with transfer function:

$$\frac{V_L}{V_{in}}=\frac{-\omega^2LC}{(1 - \omega^2LC)+j\omega RC}$$

If the output voltage is the voltage across the resistor, then we have a 1st order band-pass filter with transfer function:

$$\frac{V_R}{V_{in}}=\frac{j\omega RC}{(1 - \omega^2LC)+j\omega RC}$$

The output voltage could also be the voltage across two circuit elements in which case the sequence of circuit elements could be relevant.